# modify field value in post back not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following snippet of asp.net mvc controller code that check if state is invalid, then I will update the value of one field:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ContactInfo contactinfo)
{
    if (IsModelStateValid(GetIssues(contactinfo)))
    {
        db.ContactInfoes.Add(contactinfo);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

   contactinfo.Name+="why this is not working".
    return View(contactinfo);
}
```

Through debugging I checked that the new value of Name field is successfully passed to Model of my View, but in the render result, only the field validation fields are updated, the field value change is not rendered, Could someone help me on how to apply this change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got sort of `cache` problem, clear it with:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ContactInfo contactinfo)
{
    if (IsModelStateValid(GetIssues(contactinfo)))
    {
        db.ContactInfoes.Add(contactinfo);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Clear the model state.
    ModelState.Clear(); // <-----------------------------------------------

    // Or just remove the `Name` property:        
    ModelState.Remove("Name")

    contactinfo.Name+="why this is not working".
    return View(contactinfo);
}
```

Comment: ModelState.Clear() did the treat