# Modified view-model value in post not showing up in DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement a button to adding and removing a row using static HTML.  I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829353/modify-field-value-in-post-back-not-working) that seems to be what I want, but I found that the example doesn't work for drop-down lists.  None of the drop-down lists' options ever are marked as selected.  If I don't clear the model state, all of the old values are kept.  How can I keep my changes to the view-model?

```
// Controller action
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult DoSomething(DoSomethingViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (viewModel != null)
    {
        if (viewModel.ButtonPressed != null)
        {
            if (viewModel.ButtonPressed.Trim() == "Cancel")
            {
                return Redirect(ApplicationUtilities.CancelRequestUrl);
            }
            else if (viewModel.ButtonPressed.Trim() == "AddRow")
            {
                ModelState.Clear();

                // This only covers non-JavaScript users.

                // One for the newest one.
                viewModel.FieldOneValues.Add(String.Empty);
                viewModel.FieldTwoValues.Add(String.Empty);
                viewModel.FieldThreeValues.Add(null);

                return View(viewModel);
            }
            else if (viewModel.ButtonPressed.Trim().StartsWith("Remove"))
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                String[] split = viewModel.ButtonPressed.Split('-');
                if (split.Length == 2)
                {
                    Int32 indexToRemove;
                    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[([0-9]+)\]");
                    Match match = regex.Match(split[1]);
                    if (match.Success && Int32.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out indexToRemove))
                    {
                        viewModel.FieldOneValues.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
                        viewModel.FieldTwoValues.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
                        viewModel.FieldThreeValues.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
                    }
                }

                return View(viewModel);
            }
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return WhateverIsDoneOnSuccess(viewModel);
    }
    else
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}

// View Model
public class DoSomethingViewModel
{
    public DoSomethingViewModel()
    {
        this.FieldOneValues = new List<String>();
        this.FieldTwoValues = new List<String>();
        this.FieldThreeValues = new List<Int32?>();
    }

    public virtual IList<String> FieldOneValues { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<String> FieldTwoValues { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Int32?> FieldThreeValues { get; set; }
    public virtual String ButtonPressed { get; set; }
}

<!-- Spark View -->
<tr each="var fieldOneValue in Model.FieldOneValues">
    <td headers="FieldOneTh">${Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.FieldOneValues[fieldOneValueIndex])}</td>
    <td headers="FieldTwoTh">${Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.FieldTwoValues[fieldOneValueIndex])}</td>
    <td headers="FieldThreeTh">
        ${Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.fieldOneValueIndex], new { disabled="disabled", @readonly="readonly" })}
        ${Html.DropDownListFor(
            m => m.FieldThreeValues[fieldOneValueIndex]
          , ApplicationUtilities.FieldThreeSelectListItems
          , " "
        )}
    </td>
    <td headers="AddRemoveTh">
        <button name="${Html.NameFor(m => m.ButtonPressed)}" class="Remove" type="submit" value="Remove-[${fieldOneValueIndex}]">Remove</button>
        <button if="fieldOneValueIsLast" name="${Html.NameFor(m => m.ButtonPressed)}" class="Add" type="submit" value="AddRow">Add</button>
    </td>
</tr>

<!-- HTML Output -->
<tr>
    <td headers="FieldOneTh"><textarea cols="20" id="FieldOneValues_0_" name="FieldOneValues[0]" rows="2">
</textarea></td>
    <td headers="FieldTwoTh"><textarea cols="20" id="FieldTwoValues_0_" name="FieldTwoValues[0]" rows="2">
</textarea></td>
    <td headers="FieldThreeTh">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Nullable`1 must be a number." disabled="disabled" id="FieldThreeValues_0_" name="FieldThreeValues[0]" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="0" />
        <select id="FieldThreeValues_0_" name="FieldThreeValues[0]"><option value=""> </option>
<option value="0">Option 1</option>
<option value="1">Option 2</option>
<option value="2">Option 3option>
</select>
    </td>
    <td headers="AddRemoveTh">
        <button name="ButtonPressed" class="Remove" type="submit" value="Remove-[0]">Remove</button>
        <button name="ButtonPressed" class="Add" type="submit" value="AddRow">Add</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: "If I don't clear the model state, all of the old values are kept." I really apologize but the only appropriate response to that is "DUH". That's what `ModelState` is for: tracking posted values. If you clear it, then yeah, that all goes away. So why are you clearing it in the first place?

Comment: I'm clearing it because when I try to remove a row, it preserves the old values.  The effect is that clicking on the remove button for any row removes the last row instead.  The values in the model state override the values in the view model.  What I want it to do is use the values in the view model instead.

Comment: Sound's like you're just setting a flag or something on the row indicating that it should be removed. Either use JS to literally remove the row from the DOM so it's not posted back or handle the removal process in its own postback.

Comment: I know 99.9999% of people have JavaScript enabled, but the fallback should always be that things work if JavaScript fails.  Plus I'm curious; I think there should be a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

> Plus I'm curious; I think there should be a way to do this.

There is, but you have to handle the post correctly. It's situations like these why PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) is recommended. When you click something like a remove button for a particular item, it's not appropriate to save all the other fields and do whatever else would happen when the whole form is actually submitted. All the user indicated was that they wanted to remove this one item.

Therefore, when you get the post, you remove that item from the database or wherever it's persisted and then you *redirect* back to the original form if that's what you want. The redirect process updates the page state so that the item is now gone and the rest of the form can then be edited without carrying around stale data. What you're trying to do is remove the item, but then just return the view directly which still has the posted item in the data backing it. That's where your problem is.

I think you went down this path because you're trying to maintain any edits the user made to other areas of the form, but that's simply not going to be possible. However, you do have some options:

1. Don't actually have a button that removes the item right this minute. Instead, provide a checkbox or something that indicates the item should be deleted when the user posts the entire form. Then you can save the all the form data, remove the indicated items, and redirect afterwards like you should.
2. Use local storage to save the user's edits on the client-side, and then read them back from local storage after the page loads again, following the redirect. However, this requires JS.
3. Use AJAX to submit the request to remove the item, and then remove the row from the DOM. However, this requires JS.

Also, remember that it's entirely possible to progressively enhance your form. So, you can implement #1 *and* #3, and then if JS isn't available, #1 still serves as a fallback.

Comment: I'm already using PRG in loads of other places, and I have the progressive enhancements already done, though not quite how you suggest.  Part of what I'm not understanding is why DropDownListFor loses the value when the other elements generated by helpers don't seem to.  In the HTML output, why is there `value="0"` in the `input` element I generated for debugging, but `<option value="0">Option 1</option>` doesn't have `selected="selected"`?

Comment: Your answer is an excellent answer, but it doesn't answer my particular question. I really do want to just keep the changes made to the view model in the controller action that responds to the POST request without redirecting.